# Why can’t Mac compress files faster than ~60MB/sec or so?

Tags: finder, file-sharing, compression

It seems like this has remained relatively constant over the last 5+ years or at least as long as I have been paying attention. Files on an internal SSD can be copied to other drives much faster… files can be unzipped much faster… but when it comes to compressing, it’s one monotonous trudge. (In my workflow I often zip up 10-30GB files which is why I notice.) Not a problem, just an inconvenience and a curiosity.

Is compressing files limited to using only a single CPU core or something like that?

Comment: Most compression algorithms are sequential, they can't usually take advantage of multiple cores.

Comment: It would depend on your compression software. macOS uses some extremely fast compression for swapping virtual memory to ssd, but your compression software won’t be using that. Compression works sequentially, but you could easily turn a file into 128MB chunks and let each core compress one. Just nobody does it.

Comment: Oh interesting! If it continues to be a challenge I will look more into separating a file into “chunks”. I have noticed that when I am zipping multiple files, they seem to all go the same speed as when I am just zipping one!